# Declare functions in ASP.NET WebPages

Tags: asp.net-webpages

Is it possible to declare functions (as you would do in C# not javascript) or create classes in ASP.NET Web Pages?

How about in MVC, in the View files?

If not, is there anyway to do event handling in Web Pages? (Again, NOT javascript eventhandling)

Comment: That's just writing ASP.NET web pages *without* code behind. You'll write your C# code directly in the aspx file.

Comment: Do you want to declare it specifically in the .aspx or does it not matter weather its in the .aspx.cs file.

Comment: It can be anywhere. I actually have a .cshtml file, but that's really the same as an .aspx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own functions within .cshtml files. This article explains the `functions` keyword and how to use it: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/173/The-Difference-Between-@Helpers-and-@Functions-In-WebMatrix. If you include it in the .cshtml file that also makes use of the function, you cannot call it from other pages. If you wanted to do that, you can add a function to a .cshtml file and then put that in App_Code.

There are no events as such in ASP.NET Web Pages. You can check to see if a page has been posted back using the [IsPost property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.helperpage.ispost%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

If you want to make use of reusable utility methods in MVC, you are better off taking the more traditional approach of creating static classes and adding your methods there. App_Code is really for Web Site projects (ASP.NET Web Pages) as opposed to Web Application projects (whcih is what MVC apps are).

Comment: can you subscribe the functions you define (with the function keyword) to the javascript events (such as OnClick)?

Comment: You can't write a C# function for a javascript event.C# executes on the server. Javascript executes on the client machine once the page (HTML, text, css etc) has been generated and transmitted to the browser.

Comment: But you can in MVC. I thought maybe WebPages also sends the event back to the server. Maybe the server would keep a track of the functions on that page and execute them, e.g. make a controller file out of the functions.

Comment: I'm confused what it is you want. You can use AJAX to respond to a javascript event and then make an asynchronous request to an endpoint that invokes a C# function on the server. But the C# function doesn't "subscribe" to a particular event. It doesn't know what happened on the client to cause it to be invoked.

Comment: can you call the C# function with AJAX? I thought you can only use AJAX for file requests (or scripts that run on the client).

Comment: You can use AJAX to make any type of HTTP request.